# How to recover a keystore password after you forget it

Tags: java, android, keystore, android-keystore

I have a set of applications and I always use one signature for all applications before publishing them in the store and I happened to forget the keystore password even though I have a username. Is it an effective way to retrieve the password?

Answer (score 13):

If you lost the keystore password - maybe this gist helps:

https://gist.github.com/zach-klippenstein/4631307

Of course - it does not recover the old password and does not work for the key password itself. Apart from that - way too often the keystore password is left "changeit".

Comment: You got me... It's "changeit" indeed, thank you very much!

Comment: yup! changeit.. I won't forget it